# MongoDB multiple stages update

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection `users` which includes array of objects under property `roles`. Each object (role) has `isDefault` property. I need two-step update and wondering if it is possible inside single DB query:

1. Reset `isDefault` in every object inside array to `false`;
2. Set `isDefault` in specific object.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from v4.2 you can benefit from [update with aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

If I melt your 2 stages in a single [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) with conditional value for `isDefault`, the update may look like this:

```
db.users.update({
  { "roles": { $exist: true } }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "roles": {
        $map: {
          input: "$roles",
          as: "one",
          in: {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$one",
              {
                "isDefault": {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$one.<the specific object selector>",
                    <the specific object field  value>
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true,
  "upsert": false
})
```